# Waiting for Input C++

Tags: c++, input, get, cin

My assignment dictates that unless something is entered by the keyboard, nothing will happen. However, I cannot prompt the user to enter anything. My loop looks something like this:

```
while(true){
    "Enter a string to continue:  ";
    //wait for input
    //based on input, do this.
}
```

The program basically pauses until the user enters a string input without being prompted to, if that makes sense.

The terminal will look blank until the user enters something and then my program kicks in based on the input. Would a simple cin work?

Comment: Probably need to flush the output. easy way to do this is cout << "prompt" << endl;

Comment: I can't use a prompt. My program stalls indefinitely until the user inputs a string. I tried cin.get, but that's only for char.

Comment: Are you expecitng the user to have to press enter to signal the end of the string?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to create a string variable to hold the users input. For example,

```
string name;
cin >> name;
cout << "you entered: " << name << endl;
```

now name will store the users input.

Comment: That's not really what I want. I've tried that and it did not work in my program. Basically, I cannot have a cout in my while loop, i just put it as an example. the user puts in the inputs without being prompted to.

Comment: why don't you just remove the prompt? I updated my answer, now rather than prompting the user the program will just sit and wait until user input and store it in a string for use.

Comment: Oh man, why didn't I think of that? I should have done that all along. I was thinking that wouldn't work. But it does, thanks.

Comment: if that works please make it the accepted answer for others to see. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    for(;;){ // same meaning as while(true){
        std::string str;
        std::cout << "Enter a string to continue:  " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> str; // or std::getline(std::cin, str);
        // based on the input, do something
    }
}
```